# Does it matter where I was vaccinated to enter Greece?

Tags: europe, covid-19, greece, vaccinations

I was vaccinated in Australia, but I have been issued also with an Italian EU green pass attesting to my vaccination. I'm filling out the Greece passenger locator form right now and it's asking me where I was vaccinated, does it matter if it wasn't in the EU?

Comment: I suppose some countries vaccines aren't "recognized" by EU authorities. So if you e.g. had been vaccinated in Russia (hence with Russian vaccine), chances would be the vaccination would "count".

Comment: if you have a green pass, probably it doesn't matter, but forms must be generic, and adding "conditionals" may just make more difficult to fill and also more error prone. And because Greek is "Greek" for many people, standardized forms helps.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if the country plays a role but Greece accepts tourists that are vaccinated with the following vaccines:

The EU recognized:

-Astra Zeneca

-Pfizer

-Moderna

-Johnsons & Johnsons

Other vaccines also accepted:

-Novavax

-Sinovac

-Sinopharm

-Cansino Biologics

-Sputnik V

Because things change all the time though I would reccommend checking with the Greek Embassy of your country to be sure.